# Css animation to extend button text on hover

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I want to show more text on a button when it's hovered and I want the button to shrink and grow with the extended text.

I need a general solution since the text on the button and thereby its width will depend on the users choice of language.

This is my (currently not working) attempt

```css
.hover-value {
  display: inline-block;
  visibility: collapse;
  width: 0%;
  -webkit-transition: width 2s;
  transition: width 2s;
  overflow: hidden;
}
button:hover .hover-value {
  visibility: visible;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<button>
  Result
  <span class="hover-value">Add new result</span>
</button>
```

Also on JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/JohanGovers/46392xss/

I'm using jQuery and bootstrap in my project but would like to solve this with css if possible. I've tried playing around with visibility property as suggested in other SO answers but to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

For the nicest animation I've decided to animate the `max-width` property. This is because, at the moment, you cannot animate to or from `width:auto`.

(Set `max-width:7rem` to something greater than the length of your text.)

To avoid a bunch of aligning CSS I used `display: inline-flex` as this perfectly aligned it without using `vertical-align` and whatnot. (If this is a problem it can be changed.)

Then I used `white-space:nowrap` to force all the text onto one line so that it animated more smoothly.

```css
button span {
  max-width: 0;
  -webkit-transition: max-width 1s;
  transition: max-width 1s;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
button:hover span {
  max-width: 7rem;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">
  Result 
  <span>New result</span>
</button>
<button id="btn">
  Result 
  <span>Different text</span>
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks this works well in Chrome and IE 10+ but in Firefox 42.0 the texts don't align. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Ah that was probably to do with `inline-flex`, does the updated answer solve the problem?

Comment: Yes it does. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Done but with quirky animation:

***Updated***- now smooth result thanks to **jaunt**, who suggested to add this `white-space: nowrap;` to the button css

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/cqaxp1m9/1/)

```css
button {
  width: 53px;
  height: 21px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: width 1s;
  transition: width 1s;
  white-space: nowrap; /*this was suggested by jaunt, thanks */
}
button:hover {
  width: 145px;
  -webkit-transition: width 1s;
  transition: width 1s;
}
button:hover::after {
  content: 'Add new result';
}
```

```html
<h3>This is what I've got so far.</h3>

<button id="btn">
  Result
</button>
```

Comment: If you add `white-space: nowrap;` to `button` then the text is forced onto one line, which is causing your 'quirky' animation.

Comment: @jaunt, thanks a lot, I've never faced a problem where I needed it, this why I never think of it, thanks for reminding me!

Answer (score 0):

Try this way you will get the output as you like.

```css
.hover-value {
    display: inline-block;
    /*visibility: collapse;*/
    -webkit-transition: width 2s;
    transition: width 2s;
    overflow: hidden;
    display:none;
  top:3px;
    position:relative;
}

button:hover .hover-value {
    visibility: visible;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<button>
    Result
    <span class="hover-value">Add new result</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a similar effect with the font-size.

Change it from 0px to inherit or e spezific size.

```
.hover-value {
    font-size: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: font-size 1s;
    transition: font-size 1s;
}

button:hover .hover-value {
    font-size: inherit;
}
```

See e [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/46392xss/1/) on jsfiddle.

Comment: Nice one, try to change the width of the span instead it might look better

Comment: fix width-attributs are dangerous. What happens, when the Text-Length change?!

Comment: since it is saying "*add new result*" I don't think he's going to change the text of the button dynamically, and he can change the width if he wants, the only problem with growing font size is that the animation looks kind of childish

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you, I have shared the jfiddle link at the bottom for your reference, but pasting the relevant code here.

```
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

h3{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    line-height:1.5em;
}
button{
   text-align:left;
   width:7.5em; 
   overflow:hidden;
   transition:width 1s ease-in-out;
}
button:hover{
     width:20em;
     transition:width 1s ease-in-out;
}
button:focus{
    outline:none;
}
button span.sthGroup{
    display:block;
    width:20em;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
</style>

<h3>button</h3>
<button class="" type="button">
    <span class="sthGroup">
        <span>some text here</span>
        <span>some additional text here</span>
    </span>
</button>
```

[Sample for your reference](https://jsfiddle.net/vssadineni/pdhmhwnz/)

Comment: @Mi-Creativity thank you for the edit, yes that was a mistake. :)

Answer (score 0):

**CSS Based Solution**

```css
.bookNow {
  width: 35px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.4s;
  height: 35px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  border-radius: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

header {
  display: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.bookNow:hover {
  width: 200px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  border-radius: 35px;
}

.bookNow:hover header {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="bookNow" title='Book Now'>
  <h1>X</h1>
  <header>Book An Appointment</header>
</div>
```